# Reading and processing html with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, perl, angularjs

My perl program reads (by get(URL) ) web pages and processes the data.

This works fine but recently I got an web page with AngularJS.

This means get(URL) does not deliver the completed content because the AngularJS code changes the delivered html content within the browser.

Is there a way to get the completed content. F.i. by sending the code to a browser module?

Thanks,
W. Curth

Comment: While in theory you could try to parse the index.html and also download the script-resources and then run that in Phantom.js or something similar, I think that in practice this would be quite a lot of work and fairly hard to automate.

Comment: Watch ouf for JQuery Mobile pages as you will face a similiar problem in that JQM usies the initial html page as a template to build upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [WWW:Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) to get the rendered page.

```
  use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
  my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
  $mech->get( $url, ':content_file' => $tempfile );
  print $mech->content( format => 'html' );
```

If it is not working you could execute a custom JS code or process the DOM tree.