# Can Ruby's Mechanize process rendered web pages?

Tags: ruby

I want to scrape a page after its Javascript has fully rendered everything on it. Of course, Mechanize alone cannot do that. My computer has limited resources, so I want to avoid screen scrapers like Selenium and Watir, which open memory-hogging browser windows.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676847/reading-and-processing-html-with-angularjs) mentions WWW::Mechanize::Firefox for Perl, which supposedly processes rendered web pages.

Does something like this exist in Ruby?

Comment: You might find something you can use in this list: https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers

Comment: There's also [this writeup](https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2014/2/12/automate-tasks-on-the-web-with-ruby-and-capybara/) which details using PhantomJS (a headless webkit-based browser).

Answer (score 0):

`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` does exactly what you say you don't want to do -- it integrates with a browser window of Firefox.